# Missing "Connection" option after clicking .sql files

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL Server 2012 and I no longer see `Connection`, `Execute SQL` and other options in `.sql` files context menu. Furthermore .sql files have icons like .txt files. 
What am I missing here?

Screenshot: [image: http://s21.postimg.org/47nzhdok7/sqlserver.jpg]

Solution in the screenshot comes from the book: [Pro SQL Server 2012 BI Solutions](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1289/)

Comment: This isn't a programming question and would be more on-topic on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the `.SQL` file and open it. Then right click on the source will give you the `Connection` and `Execute SQL` options.

This is the same Solution that you provided in the question:
[image]

If you are missing the `Transact-SQL Editor` option under `Data` menu, you've probably missed the SQL file association.

Do this, as [`here`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/27ef7c94-4410-4925-ab22-3fec475b1885) suggests:

1. Load up your **ISO** or **DVD VS2010** Installer in an explorer window
2. Go to the **WCU** folder
3. Go to the **DAC** folder
4. Install these MSIs

   - DACFramework_enu.msi
   - DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
   - TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

I think another option is to install [`SQL Server Data Tools`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014).

Comment: Options related to executing/connecting still doesn't appear.

Comment: @user2211552, would you post a full screenshot of your screen? Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Still nothing. Full screenshot of my screen:
http://s8.postimg.org/svatdjv6d/sql.jpg

Comment: Check if you have `Transact-SQL Editor` under `Data` menu. If not, I think you are missing the SQL extension association. Let me know if that's the case. Then I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I have Transact-SQL Editor and this was issue of missing the SQL extension association (right click -> Open with...). Problem solved.